# Multiple Instances of Firefox and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, firebug, firefox-3, firefox3.5

After upgrading to FF3.5, I noticed Firebug is slower. A lot slower, it is annoying to debug web applications and have to wait 5 seconds to open a tab.

After some googling, I got FF3.0 and FF3.5 running side by side, with different profiles. Now I can use GMail, Google Docs, and all the Google Apps we use here at work in FF3.5 (a lot faster) and debug my application in FF3.0.

I would like to set my Visual Studio 2008 to start my web application in FF3.0, but I don't see how to pass parameters after adding a new browser in the "View in Browser" dialog.

Anyone tried that before?

Thanks!

Comment: I workarounded it.
Rich Seller has a good point there, I will accept that as correct, but I did something different.
I just changed VS settings to not automatically open a page when start debugging and had my new FF3.0 profile to open my local app as start page. If FF3.0 is closed, it will open, otherwise I'm just refreshing with the good old F5. ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [portable version of firefox 3.0.12](http://portableapps.com/news/2009-07-28_-_firefox_portable_3.0.12), as it will run in parallel with the "proper" version.

Comment: This is a valid comment, but passing parameters inside the dialog in Visual Studio would look cleaner. If nothing else appears, I will try it. Thanks!